# Why is this HashMap being passed as reference

Tags: java, hashmap

I have two HashMaps defined as follows:

```
HashMap EventTable = new HashMap();
HashMap MainTable = new HashMap ();
```

Now, suppose I insert some data into EventTable:

```
EventTable.put("name", "Test Event Name");
```

Then, suppose we insert the EventTable into the MainTable:

```
MainTable.put("table", EventTable);
```

and then print out MainTable:

```
{table={name=Test Event Name}}
```

Now if I modify Event Table as follows:

```
 EventTable.put("more names", "More test events");
```

This changes the MainTable as well:

```
{table={more names=More test events, name=Test Event Name}}
```

So obviously, EventTable is being passed by reference to MainTable.

I don't understand why EventTable is being passed by reference.

Ideally I would like to reuse the EventTable HashMap to create other entries, while retaining my  old entries, so I would like to pass EventTable by value.

**EDIT:**

Forgot to mention this in the main question, but when I add a String to the MainTable, that does not change when I modify the string afterwards. So how is the behavior is different for the String?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference

Comment: EventTable is not passed by reference - if you reassign EventTable with `EventTable = new HashMap` after having inserted it in MainTable, it won't change the content of MainTable.

Comment: Ok, I think i get it. EventTable is still pointing to the same location as the HashMap entry, so when I reassign Event Table, it doesn't affect the HashMap entry anymore, am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because, even though Java passes all arguments by value, when you pass an object, you are really passing an object reference.  if you were to set `EventTable` to a new Hashmap, the one you passed in to `MainTable` would not be changed. This article may help clear things up: http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm

Answer (score 5):

Although I would never use raw types and follow the Java naming conventions, you can do something like this to get your desired behavior:

```
mainTable.put("table", new HashMap(eventTable));
```

---

To address your edit: Strings are immutable in Java.

Answer (score 3):

as in @assylias said, parameters passed by value.

here `HashMap` can not copy the date because it could be anything. but you can create a new `HashMap` by its constructor.

```
HashMap newHashMap= new HashMap(oldHashMap);
```